# Unexpected templating type error occured on {{ ec2.instances | from_json }}: expected string or buffer?

Tags: json, ansible

I can't pass json string that is in a variable to `from_json`. I'm getting the error message from the title. The following is my "code".

```
- ec2_instance_facts:
    aws_access_key: "{{ key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret }}"
  register: ec2

- name: "Looking up stuff."
  set_fact:
    a_count: "{{ ec2.instances | from_json }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ a_count }}"
```

Any idea how to achieve that? I want to pass the json object to `json_query` afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_query` operates with Python objects. And Ansible stores data in Python objects.

The reason you see JSON on the screen is because Ansible output plugins dump objects as JSON.

You can do `{{ ec2.instances | json_query('...') }}` without any conversions.

`from_json` is required if you have some *string* with JSON data to convert it to Python object.

Comment: I already tried that but ran into https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299 but found your workaround `to_json | from_json`. Now I owe you a beer, not just upvotes ;)

Comment: It depends on your query. In some cases when you filter strings, you may be forced to use this double conversion workaround.